# Python Pandas not importing .csv. Error: pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am writing information into 2 .csv files (2 columns, separated by comma). I have ensured with time.sleep() that my desktop has enough time to write all the data to the file before pandas tries loading the information into the dataframe. It also seems like the issue remains with archorg.csv since I tried reversing the order for importing the file and pacman.csv didn't give an error, but archorg.csv still did.

```
    onlinedf = pd.read_csv('/home/kia/Code/update/data/archorg.csv')
    pacmandf = pd.read_csv('/home/kia/Code/update/data/pacman.csv')
```

When I try running this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kia/Code/update/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    ugh = main()
  File "/home/kia/Code/update/main.py", line 20, in __init__
    filemgr.loadfiles()
  File "/home/kia/Code/update/files.py", line 10, in loadfiles
    onlinedf = pd.read_csv('/home/kia/Code/update/data/archorg.csv')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 575, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 934, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1236, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 551, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Finally, I went to the interpreter and line by line entered the following:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv('/home/kia/Code/update/data/archorg.csv')
                  package     version
0          python-dulwich   0.20.45-1
1              sqlite-tcl    3.39.1-1
2              sqlite-doc    3.39.1-1
3         sqlite-analyzer    3.39.1-1
4                  sqlite    3.39.1-1
..                    ...         ...
223     python-voluptuous    0.13.1-1
224     python-tldextract     3.3.1-1
225    perl-file-mimeinfo      0.33-1
226  perl-crypt-passwdmd5      1.42-1
227      perl-test-simple  1.302191-1

[228 rows x 2 columns]
```

It seems to get the job done with no issues. I've also posted a portion of the csv file below in case there's an issue there, although I have already checked it for extra commas/whitespaces/etc.

```
package,version
python-dulwich,0.20.45-1
sqlite-tcl,3.39.1-1
sqlite-doc,3.39.1-1
sqlite-analyzer,3.39.1-1
sqlite,3.39.1-1
lemon,3.39.1-1
tp_smapi-lts,0.43-254
r8168-lts,8.050.03-9
acpi_call-lts,1.2.2-58
nvidia-lts,1:515.57-6
linux-lts-headers,5.15.55-1
linux-lts-docs,5.15.55-1
linux-lts,5.15.55-1
mattermost,7.1.1-1
node-gyp,9.1.0-1
trivy,0.30.0-1
sile,0.13.3-1
```

Edit: [repo](https://github.com/itsKia2/pacman-update-checker) added for full review.

Edit 2: Got it to work using sep= instead of delim_whitespace, and then writing to the file with csv module instead of concatenation of strings, to remove any possibility of csv formatting errors. All files shown in repo for reference.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of how do you generate and save it?

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna have added the github repo to my post.

Comment: Can you include just the part of writing data and using delay to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your csv sample worked fine for me, the puzzling part is that your other file worked fine.
i would suggest you try a work around and i hope it works

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filepath", delim_whitespace=True)
df[['Package', 'Version']] = df['package,version'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df.drop(columns = "package,version", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Okay so I tried out your solution line by line. Adding the delim_whitespace=True option got it working, whereas the other lines gave errors regarding axis not found. However at this point, when I can successfully output my dataframes (both pacmandf and onlinedf), it seems that I am missing some of my data (i.e I have 1181 rows of data and the dataframe only outputs 845 repeatedly). Using the interpreter or a standalone script to output the csv file shows me the complete data but the same things in my project just don't work. https://github.com/itsKia2/pacman-update-checker for full review.